# Google Sheets stacked bar chart showing 1 extra value and legend

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Consider this Google Sheet:

```
              6/30/2020 1/1/2021    1/1/2022
Consultant    3         4           6
Manager       0         1           1
Administrator 0         0           1
```

When I create a stacked column chart with data range A1:D4 are there 4 legends somehow.

**I have no idea how to get rid of the blue value.**

I tried removing `A1:D1` series, played around with the settings for that series, but I must leave it at `Count` to get a stacked chart.
See my chart and settings below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not been able to replicate your issue on a new sheet.

However, this Forum Help sheet I created appears to work fine. I selected the same range as you outlined in your question `A1:D4`

[image]

You can go to `File > Make a Copy` to have a play with it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AISXV03Btc9qknp04yXBxcPII3DZIixUjdB9ZmBREO0/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: That is so weird. I created a new sheet and retried all settings and now it works, *shrugs*. Thanks!